# Log rotation in nginx

Tags: nginx, logging, openresty

I've found an example of doing log rotation in Nginx [here](https://www.cambus.net/log-rotation-directly-within-nginx-configuration-file/)

But a simple test with:

```
    set $date "2018-08-24";
    access_log /home/tim/log/access-http-$date.log default;
```

produces a log file named `access-http-.log`. I'm using nginx 1.13.6 (with openresty).

**Update**

After much hacking & tweaking, I've come up with the following logrotate script to rotate the different log files that nginx produces. I've put it into /etc/logrotate. The remaining issue is that the logs don't rotate daily (I'm unsure why at present), but a `logrotate -f <filename>` produces exactly the result I want.

An interesting note is that `nginx -s reload` can be used instead of USR1. That's unfortunately not referenced in the nginx logging page but I found it (in the man page IIRC). I build openresty/nginx manually to incorporate extra modules I need so I don't get various extras that come in the packaged version like the pid keeping.

```
/path/to/log/access-http.log /path/to/log/access-https.log /path/to/log/api.log /path/to/log/error.log {
    daily
    missingok
    notifempty
    create 664 nobody tim
    dateext
    dateformat -%Y-%m-%d
    dateyesterday
    rotate 10
    su tim tim
    postrotate
        /usr/local/bin/openresty -s reload
    endscript
}
```

I figure this will be useful for anyone with a large nginx config serving both web pages and an API. I keep the http separate as I don't serve non-https pages and it keeps the script kiddie crap out of my page logs.

Comment: Have you tried actually doing what is documented in that tutorial?

Comment: I've tried the command that sets the $year, $month and $day variables. And then tried `access_log /home/tim/log/access-$year.log;` Same log file name .

Comment: I can only confirm that your simple test pasted above, works in my setup

Answer (score 4):

Just set a cron task for a minute to midnight to move the logfile and rename it with the date and then send a USR1 signal to Nginx. This will trigger it to reopen log files and create a new one for the following day.

```
59 23 * * * mv /var/log/nginx/access.log /var/log/nginx/$(date +%F).access.log && kill -USR1 $(cat /run/nginx.pid)
```

Comment: why not to use logrotate for this?

Comment: Because I can do it in a single line of bash

Comment: but then you cannot ask that one line of code to save only 14 days of historic logs, supposing that this feature is wanted.

Comment: True. I'll need a second line of code to delete the log files which are more than 14 days old.